# How to assign different template to product detail page of specific category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2.2

I have created two category "wine" and "events". I added product to each category and now I want to apply different template/design to product view page according to category.

Products in event category have different design, and so on for wine category.

How to achieve this please.

Answer (score 0):

you can set different layout for each category on the backend just go to your admin page

- go to your admin page
- select catalog
- click categories
- select sub categories you want (wine or events) on the left tree categories
- go to right side and click design tab
- you can select the theme and layout that you want apply to the categories

[image]

Comment: This doesnot change the template to product view page.

Comment: Product view page  don't have single template to change as like Magento 1. Can you provide more details about the exact block name for which you are trying to change template and version of your Magento?